# mysql->info returning null after move to new server space

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I had previously been testing a new site using XAMPP while I waited for a production space to become available. Upon moving to the new space several things no longer worked. One of them is the mysql_info function (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.info.php)

I have the following test example:

```
$collector = 'Jenny';
$sample_name = 'sample001';
$query = 'UPDATE sample SET collector_name = ? WHERE sample_name = ?';

if($stmt = $dbc ->prepare($query)) {                 
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $collector, $sample_name);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $rows_affected = $stmt ->affected_rows;
    $stmt -> close();

    //check if add was successful or not. Tell the user
    if($rows_affected >= 0){
        echo "test".$dbc->info;
        if($dbc->info == NULL){
            echo "nullll";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "update failed";
    }
}
else{
        echo "preparedfailed";
}
?>
```

This successfully outputs the result of $dbc->info as 'Rows matched: 1 Changed: 1 Warnings: 0' on the XAMPP version (using php 5.5) and returns null on the new production server which has a regular LAMP stack installed on it (using php 5.4). I cannot figure out why this is or how to fix it. Any helpful suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: have you done a php info on your hosted server? which version is? which version you got on local? which difference outside php version you can see?

Comment: @Goikiu hosted site php 5.4 and local is 5.5 Is that what you are referring to? Documentation says function supported for 5+  (http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_info.asp)

Comment: difference about configuration of mysqli module?

Comment: i am not certain I know what you mean. I have: Client API library version  5.1.73 (hosted) and Client API library version  mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 (local)

Comment: trough php_info you can see the enviroment variable, use it in both server and see if for the mysqli module there are differences